# Permitir solo una selección cuando hay mas de 2 JTables

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola tengo una interfaz en la que se agregan JTables dinamicamente, es posible quitar la selección de una tabla cuando se seleccione algún elemento de otra tabla?, es decir que solo se permita seleccionar elementos de una sola tabla y que no aparezcan multiples selecciones como en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí lo puedes hacer, pero requieres tener acceso a las tablas y escucharlas para que desselecciones todas menos una.

Para quitar la selección JTable tiene método público clearSelection();

Comment: gracias ya pude borrar las selecciones